# Eliminar elemento al presionar una tecla

Tags: javascript, canvas

El código consiste es en crear un lobo con las flechas del teclado, ya hice un código funcional, pero queda un lobo detrás como si fuera una línea de lobo.

¿Cómo hago para quitar el lobo *viejo* por decirlo así? Es decir, el lobo anterior al nuevo que se dibuja cuando presiono la tecla.

Mi código:

```js
console.log("*script is working*");

var vp = document.getElementById("villaPlatzi");

var papel = vp.getContext("2d");

var flechas = {
 UP: 38,
 DOWN: 40,
 LEFT: 37,
 RIGHT: 39,
};

document.addEventListener("keyup", moverLobo);

function moverLobo(evento)
{
 papel.drawImage(lobo.objeto, xLobo, yLobo);
 var movimientoLobo = 10;
 switch(evento.keyCode)
 {
  case flechas.UP:
  yLobo = yLobo - movimientoLobo
  break;

  case flechas.DOWN:

  yLobo = yLobo + movimientoLobo
  break;

  case flechas.LEFT:

  xLobo = xLobo - movimientoLobo
  break;

  case flechas.RIGHT:

  xLobo = xLobo + movimientoLobo
  break;

  default:
  console.log("***************************************")
  break;
 }
}

var xLobo = 150;
var yLobo = 150;

var fondo = {
 url: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/23/13/51/pattern-818713_960_720.png",
 loadState: false,
};

fondo.objeto = new Image();
fondo.objeto.src = fondo.url;
fondo.objeto.addEventListener("load", cargarFondo);

var vaca = {
 url: "https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/cow.png",
 loadState: false,
};

vaca.objeto = new Image();
vaca.objeto.src = vaca.url;
vaca.objeto.addEventListener("load", cargarVaca);

var pollo = {
 url: "https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/chicken.png",
 loadState: false,
};

pollo.objeto = new Image();
pollo.objeto.src = pollo.url;
pollo.objeto.addEventListener("load", cargarPollo);

var cerdo = {
 url: "https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/pig.png",
 loadState: false,
};

cerdo.objeto = new Image();
cerdo.objeto.src = cerdo.url;
cerdo.objeto.addEventListener("load", cargarCerdo);

var lobo = {
  url: "https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/wolf.png",
  loadState: false,
};

lobo.objeto = new Image();
lobo.objeto.src = lobo.url;
lobo.objeto.addEventListener("load", cargarLobo)

function cargarFondo()
{
 fondo.loadState = true;
 dibujar();
}
function cargarVaca()
{
 vaca.loadState = true;
 dibujar();
}
function cargarCerdo()
{
 cerdo.loadState = true;
 dibujar();
}
function cargarPollo()
{
 pollo.loadState = true;
 dibujar();
}
function cargarLobo()
{
 lobo.loadState = true;
 moverLobo();
}
function dibujar(evento)
{
 if(fondo.loadState == true)
 {
  papel.drawImage(fondo.objeto, 0, 0);
 }
 if (vaca.loadState == true)
 {
  var cantidad = aleatorio(5, 20);
  console.log("Hay " + cantidad + "vacas!");
  for(var v = 0; v < cantidad; v++)
  {
   var x = aleatorio(0, 420);
   var y = aleatorio(0, 420);
   papel.drawImage(vaca.objeto, x, y);
  }
 }
 if (pollo.loadState == true)
 {
  var cantidad = aleatorio(5, 20);
  console.log("Hay " + cantidad + "pollos!");
  for(var p = 0; p < cantidad; p++)
  {
   var x = aleatorio(0, 420);
   var y = aleatorio(0, 420);
   papel.drawImage(pollo.objeto, x, y);

  }
 }
 if (cerdo.loadState == true)
 {
  console.log("Hay " + cantidad + "cerdos!");

  var cantidad = aleatorio(5, 20);
  for(var c = 0; c < cantidad; c++)
  {
   var x = aleatorio(0, 420);
   var y = aleatorio(0, 420);
   papel.drawImage(cerdo.objeto, x, y);
  }
 }
 if (lobo.loadState == true)
 {
  console.log("el lobo esta suelto :v");
  papel.drawImage(lobo.objeto, xLobo, yLobo);
 }
}
function aleatorio (min, max)
{
 var resulato;
 resultado = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 return resultado;
}
```

```html
<canvas id ="villaPlatzi" width="400px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿Es un juego de lobos, pollos y vacas?

Comment: Ok, ¿es un juego donde aparecen al inicio varios animales en posiciones aleatorias de la pantalla y un lobo en un punto determinado que se puede mover con las flechas de dirección? Cuando mueves el lobo, aparece en la nueva posición pero permanece la imagen en su posición inicial y ¿es lo que quieres eliminar?

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil @DanicoPlayer , puedes [darla por buena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), además de recibir reputación, ayudaras a otros usuarios  que verán una respuesta aceptada y les guiará en [su búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes crear el lobo cada vez que pulsas la flechas, en este caso cuando las sueltas, para así no deje rastro. Lo hace es construir toda la granja en caca movimiento.
Espero te sirva, lo he probado y funciona, solo debes añadir un tope si no quieres que el lobo se salga del lienzo.

```js
var vp = document.getElementById("villaPlatzi")
var papel = vp.getContext("2d")
document.addEventListener("keyup", moverLobo)

var xLobo = 150
var yLobo = 100

var xVaca = new Array()
var yVaca = new Array()

var xCerdo = new Array()
var yCerdo = new Array()

var xPollo = new Array()
var yPollo = new Array()

function moverLobo(e) {
    var movimiento = 64
    var teclas =
        {
            LEFT: 37,
            UP: 38,
            RIGHT: 39,
            DOWN: 40
        }
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case teclas.LEFT:
            xLobo = xLobo - movimiento
            dibujar(xLobo, yLobo)
            break
        case teclas.UP:
            yLobo = yLobo - movimiento
            dibujar(xLobo, yLobo)
            break
        case teclas.RIGHT:
            xLobo = xLobo + movimiento
            dibujar(xLobo, yLobo)
            break
        case teclas.DOWN:
            yLobo = yLobo + movimiento
            dibujar(xLobo, yLobo)
            break
    }
}

var fondo =
    {
        url: "tile.png",
        carga: false
    }

var lobo =
    {
        url: "lobo.png",
        carga: false
    }

var vaca =
    {
        url: "vaca.png",
        carga: false
    }

var pollo =
    {
        url: "pollo.png",
        carga: false
    }

var cerdo =
    {
        url: "cerdo.png",
        carga: false
    }

lobo.imagen = new Image()
lobo.imagen.src = lobo.url
lobo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargaLobo)

fondo.imagen = new Image()
fondo.imagen.src = fondo.url
fondo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargaFondo)

vaca.imagen = new Image()
vaca.imagen.src = vaca.url
vaca.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargaVaca)

cerdo.imagen = new Image()
cerdo.imagen.src = cerdo.url
cerdo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargaCerdo)

pollo.imagen = new Image()
pollo.imagen.src = pollo.url
pollo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargaPollo)

function cargaLobo() {
    lobo.carga = true
    dibujar()
}

function cargaFondo() {
    fondo.carga = true
    dibujar()
}

function cargaPollo() {
    pollo.carga = true
    mantenerPosicion()
}

function cargaCerdo() {
    cerdo.carga = true
    mantenerPosicion()
}

function cargaVaca() {
    vaca.carga = true
    mantenerPosicion()
}

function mantenerPosicion() {
    if (vaca.carga) {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 5)
        for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6)
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70
            xVaca[i] = x
            yVaca[i] = y
        }
    }
    if (cerdo.carga) {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 5)
        for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6)
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70
            xCerdo[i] = x
            yCerdo[i] = y
        }
    }
    if (pollo.carga) {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 10)
        for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6)
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70
            xPollo[i] = x
            yPollo[i] = y
        }
    }
    dibujar()
}

function dibujar() {
    if (fondo.carga) {
        papel.drawImage(fondo.imagen, 0, 0)
    }
    if (vaca.carga) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            papel.drawImage(vaca.imagen, xVaca[i], yVaca[i])
        }
    }
    if (cerdo.carga) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            papel.drawImage(cerdo.imagen, xCerdo[i], yCerdo[i])
        }
    }
    if (pollo.carga) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            papel.drawImage(pollo.imagen, xPollo[i], yPollo[i])
        }
    }
    if (lobo.carga) {
        papel.drawImage(lobo.imagen, xLobo, yLobo)
    }
}

function aleatorio(max, min) {
    var numero_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
    return numero_aleatorio
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D

Comment: Como ya te dije @DanicoPlayer , puedes dar por aceptada una de las respuestas marcando la "V" debajo de las flechas y así otros se beneficiaran, al igual que te hará ir cogiendo reputación en el sitio. Suerte

Answer (score 0):

Veo que hay ya una respuesta. Esta es la mía.

1. es necesario comprobar que **todas** las imágenes están cargadas antes de dibujar, de lo contrario podrías encontrarte con el fondo encima de la imágenes. Una manera fácil de hacerlo es poner las imágenes dentro del HTML y utilizar el evento `window.onload` Si no quieres ver las imágenes las puedes esconder dentro de la etiqueta canvas - por ejemplo.
2. cuando quieres mover cosas en el canvas, con cada paso tienes que borrarlo todo y re dibujarlo. Para hacerlo necesitas utilizar el método `clearRect` : `papel.clearRect(0, 0, vp.width, vp.height);` Después de borrarlo todo necesitas volver a dibujar todo, y las vacas y los cerdos y los pollos tienen que quedarse en la misma posición si no quieres moverlos. Para esto necesitas primero crearlos y guardarlos en un array de cerdos vacas y pollos. Para esto he creado las funciones function `crearVacas`, `crearPollos`. . .

```js
var vp = document.getElementById("villaPlatzi");
var papel = vp.getContext("2d");
vp.width = 420;
vp.height = 420;

var xLobo = 150;
var yLobo = 150;
var movimientoLobo = 10;

var flechas = {
  UP: 38,
  DOWN: 40,
  LEFT: 37,
  RIGHT: 39
};

var vacas = [];
var pollos = [];
var cerdos = [];

document.addEventListener("keyup", moverLobo);

function moverLobo(evento) {
  papel.clearRect(0, 0, vp.width, vp.height);

  switch (evento.keyCode) {
    case flechas.UP:
      yLobo = yLobo - movimientoLobo;
      break;

    case flechas.DOWN:
      yLobo = yLobo + movimientoLobo;
      break;

    case flechas.LEFT:
      xLobo = xLobo - movimientoLobo;
      break;

    case flechas.RIGHT:
      xLobo = xLobo + movimientoLobo;
      break;

    default:
      console.log("***************************************");
      break;
  }

  dibujar();
}

function dibujar() {
  papel.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0);
  for (var v = 0; v < vacas.length; v++) {
    papel.drawImage(vaca, vacas[v][0], vacas[v][1]);
  }
  for (var p = 0; p < pollos.length; p++) {
    papel.drawImage(pollo, pollos[p][0], pollos[p][1]);
  }
  for (var c = 0; c < cerdos.length; c++) {
    papel.drawImage(cerdo, cerdos[c][0], cerdos[c][1]);
  }
  papel.drawImage(lobo, xLobo, yLobo);
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  crearVacas();
  crearPollos();
  crearCerdos();

  dibujar();
};

function crearVacas() {
  var cantidad = aleatorio(2, 5);
  //console.log("Hay " + cantidad + "vacas!");
  for (var v = 0; v < cantidad; v++) {
    var x = aleatorio(0, 380);
    var y = aleatorio(0, 380);
    vacas.push([x, y]);
  }
}

function crearPollos() {
  var cantidad = aleatorio(2, 5);
  //console.log("Hay " + cantidad + "pollos!");
  for (var p = 0; p < cantidad; p++) {
    var x = aleatorio(0, 380);
    var y = aleatorio(0, 380);
    pollos.push([x, y]);
  }
}

function crearCerdos() {
  //console.log("Hay " + cantidad + "cerdos!");
  var cantidad = aleatorio(2, 5);
  for (var c = 0; c < cantidad; c++) {
    var x = aleatorio(0, 380);
    var y = aleatorio(0, 380);
    cerdos.push([x, y]);
  }
}

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  var resulato;
  resultado = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return resultado;
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id ="villaPlatzi" width="400px" height="300px">
<img id="fondo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/23/13/51/pattern-818713_960_720.png" />
<img id="vaca" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/cow.png" />
<img id="cerdo" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/pig.png" />
<img id="pollo" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/chicken.png" />
<img id="lobo" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/wolf.png" />
</canvas>
```

Espero que sea útil

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D